# Guidance on installing Steelseries engine 3 with wine?

Tags: wine

maybe anyone could provide any instructions on how to install Steelseries engine 3 with wine ? It does not work with out of the box wine, it starts, but is non responsive. Using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Any ideas on what could I try would be extremely welcomed.

Comment: Whenever you try to run something with wine, the first place to look for solutions is [winehq](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34833&iTestingId=104444). Unfortunately, it seems that nobody has managed to get it to work yet. Applications that deal with hardware don't work with wine in most cases. But since there are many competent software developers amongst Linux users who like the idea of open source, you can find Linux alternatives for many devices. See e.g. [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/steelseries/comments/7pziji/steelseries_engine_linux_support/).